# Limit availableProcessors

Tags: java, linux, cpu-usage

I had a problem a while ago whilst using Solaris that I wanted to limit the number of CPUs that Java could see (that was returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. I thought I had it and I was given some info for Linux and took it on faith. I was told that using `taskset` would limit the number of CPUs that java would use (which is true, it does) but it does not change what is returned by `availableProcessors()`.

I've searched quite a bit to find some way of changing this `availableProcessors()` return value and I haven't managed to find anything. Does anyone know a way to limit it or why `taskset -c 0,1 java -cp ./ Test` would not work.

Test.java

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
  }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not surprising that taskset won't work here, since it's a command that sets scheduler parameters, whereas availableProcessors() would not have any reason to query the scheduler.

Note that in your example, taskset isn't merely limiting you to two processors; it is limiting you to two specific processors (0 and 1).

I wonder if you can use crosscutting (AOP) or byte code generation to wrap the availableProcessors() call?